# How to place button in center on image in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place three buttons right in the center in the vertical alignment but on the image in Bootstrap 4. I am unable to do so I have also tried with applying `position:relative` on the image and `position:absolute` on the buttons but it is also not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid headerimage" style="padding:0 !important">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0 !important">
      <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="placeholder 960" class="img-responsive" >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Teacher</button>
   <button class="btn btn-success">Student</button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning">Administrator</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my css code .

```
.img-responsive{
  width:100% !important;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px !important;
}
```

I am stucked at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your buttons in relative position and your image in absolut position, you can move the buttons on the image with the margins.

Comment: which is the best thing to place the buttons direct in the center with margin:0 auto ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it for you https://jsfiddle.net/qynck1gp/1/

CSS

```
.btn-wrapper{ text-align:center; position:absolute; bottom: 0px; margin: 0 auto; width:100%;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid headerimage" style="padding:0 !important">
 <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0 !important">
  <img src="https://www.digitalplatforms.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Website-Design-Background.jpg" alt="placeholder 960" class="img-responsive" >
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Teacher</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Student</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Administrator</button>
  </div>
```